# Nativescript background http how to response once complete event returns

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am using `nativescript-background-http` to upload an image. The code from the component, calls a service to post the image to an API:

```
camera.takePicture(options)
            .then(function (imageAsset: ImageAsset) {

                imageUploadService.uploadImage(imageAsset.android);
```

I would like to be able to instead subscribe to this upload method, which currently looks like this:

```
uploadImage(fileUri) {
   ...
   var task = this.session1.multipartUpload(params, request);
   task.on("progress", logEvent);
   task.on("error", logEvent);
   task.on("complete", complete);

}
```

Is there a way to have the function return an observable once the function has completed?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the solution. In the component like this:

```
let imageUpload = imageUploadService.uploadImage(imageAsset.android);
imageUpload.on("complete", a => {
    console.log('upload complete')
});
```

Whilst the service returns a task:

```
uploadImage(fileUri) : Task {
    ...
    return this.session1.multipartUpload(params, request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only needed to notify when upload complete then you can return promise and use it.

```
camera.takePicture(options)
            .then(function (imageAsset: ImageAsset) {

                imageUploadService.uploadImage(imageAsset.android).then((data)=>{
                    console.log("completed data",data)
                });
            }
uploadImage(fileUri) {
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      ...
      var task = this.session1.multipartUpload(params, request);
      task.on("progress", logEvent);
      task.on("error", logEvent);
      task.on("complete", (data)=>{
          console.log("complete");
          resolve(data);
      });
   });
}
```